# Remove cloned item and update original

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 boxes with 3 items inside, onClick of "edit" button from any box, I am cloning these list items and showing in Modal box with Remove icon.

Eg: If I remove an `Item 14` from Modal window which is inside `box 2`, and click on Save button, modal should close and removed item also should get out of `box 2` and if I do the same for `Box 1` etc..., it should do the same...

**[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/t4uuk3xe/2/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".editBtn", function(){
    var boxNameDefault = $(this).closest(".box-header").find("h6").text();  
    $("input.newBoxName").val(boxNameDefault);  
    $(this).closest(".box-header").next(".box-content").find("ul").clone().appendTo(".modal-body .modal-items"); 
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove-item", function(){
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});

$(document).on("click", ".modalSaveBtn", function(){
    //$(this).closest(".modal-items").appendTo(".box"); // Need Help here
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have to put these in a modal, rather than having the 'edit' button add a 'remove' button to the existing panel and make the h6 editable? I feel like that may be a better user experience?

Comment: **@Rory McCrossan**.. Yes, we have lot of onclick events inside page, so boss suggested to edit from modal instead inline :(

Comment: If you look at @P.Frank's answer below, he brings up a good point, once you go back to edit again, it re-clones all the information back, instead of clearing and cloning - good lookin out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want make this clearly, you can add id on all your box.

I create a table contain all delete element and i check when you save each element.

**Eg:**

```
asDel = []
asDel.push($(this).closest("li").attr("id"))
```

**UPDATE**

For remove previous content, just add:

```
$(".modal-body .modal-items").html("")
```

Please try:
https://jsfiddle.net/yz37L77L/1/

Comment: Hi **@ P. Frank**... it is working as expected.. but, if I click again on Edit button, options are loading twice :(